# Launching an linux executable not from the command line

Tags: gui

If you have an executable file *.out that you launch from the GUI (let's say by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in Fedora and typing it's name), what happens if that file tries to read or print to standard out/**standard in**?  What actuary happens underneath. Are these file descriptors even created when not launching from the terminal? Are they accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is essentially the same as starting a terminal, running the commandline with `&` at the end to run it in the background and closing the terminal while the program is still running. Depending on how exactly the program is launched from the GUI, you might be able to access standard error in `~/.xsession-errors` or the equivalent file that your window manager uses.

In general, standard out and standard in of a program launched this way will not be accessible; they will usually point to `/dev/null`. Note however that you can redirect input and output using `<` and `>`, e.g. `program < file.in > file.out`.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously - if it reads form stdin read fails
If ir writes to stdout - it gets discarded
Stderr is collected where Lars said.

Comment: This is poorly punctuated, poorly spelled, slightly insulting (if it was "obvious" to rubixibuc, (s)he wouldn't have asked the question), and adds nothing to Lars's answer. What is the point?